# If A:B is 2:3, B:C is 4:5 and C:D is 6:8. Find A:B:C:D

Tags: ratio

If A:B is 2:3, B:C is 4:5 and C:D is 6:8. Find A:B:C:D?

> I am able to find A:C , B:D.

$\frac{A}{C} =  \frac{A}{B} × \frac{B}{C}$

$\frac{B}{D} = \frac{B}{C} × \frac{C}{D}$

But I am not able to find A:B:C:D.

Comment: I think the difficulty here is largely notational.  While $A:B$ is commonly used to denote a ratio of two items (often of lengths without units needed), extending this convention to multiple items is less familiar.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given,

$A:B = 2:3$

$A=2x, B=3x$

$B:C = 4:5$

$B=4x, C=5x$

Now in above two ratios in first B has 3x value and in second B has 4x value. Take LCM of 3x, 4x. You have 12x.

To make the value of B in first ratio to 12x . Multiply first ratio with 4x and in other ratio with 3x.

You have,

$A:B = 8x:12x$   and $B:C = 12x:15x$

On combining these two,

$A:B:C = 8x:12x:15x$

Now,

$C:D = 6:8$

$C = 6x, D = 8x$

Now in above two ratios in first C has 15x value and in second C has 6x value. Take LCM of 15x, 6x. You have 30x.

To make the value of C in first ratio to 30x . Multiply first ratio with 2x and in other ratio with 5x.

$A:B:C = 16x:24x:30x$

$C:D = 30x:40x$

On combining these two,

$A:B:C:D = 16x:24x:30x:40x$

If eliminate x.

We have $A:B:C:D = 16:24:30:40$

You can also divide ratio by 2 because all terms have 2 in common.

Comment: Sir, everything is clear. But how did you combine the ratios?

Comment: Just think that duplicated value not allowed.

Comment: Like you have A:B:C so on combining with C:D its become A:B:C:C:D. But not to repeat any value so it is A:B:C:D. Similarly for right hand side values.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very very much.

Comment: Mine pleasure. Happy to help you.

Comment: One more thing. Your question is good but you have to edit it to stop down vote responses from others. So in your question write how you are getting A:C and B:D. Then write can't find A:B:C:D.

Comment: Yes .. Thanks for the suggestion.